# How to write if else statements using protractor in typescript

Tags: typescript, protractor

```
 var newfilter = browser.$('.filter-names')
                        .$('ul sd-action-trigger[text="New Filter  "]')
                        .$('a');

 newfilter.isPresent().then((isPresent: boolean,) => {
     if (isPresent) {

     } else {

     }
 });
```

I dont know but it gives me error.Basically i want to chck in my code id New filter is present do if part otherwise else part.It gives me error that expected 2 arguments but got 1

Comment: And if you try to remove the comma from newfilter.isPresent().then((isPresent: boolean,)? It seems that you are trying to pass "isPresent: boolean, other parameter". I made myself understood?

Comment: Agree with @Gabriel, it should be `(isPresent: boolean)`. One more `,` after `boolean` should be removed.